# Returning (Passing Around) A Function Call in Python/Tornado?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tornado

So I'm creating the back end for a web-based game in python. Currently it works like this...

> WebSocket Handler receives message...
>
> WebSocket Handler calls message handler...
>
> Message Handler calls Game class functions...
>
> Game class calls other classes to update information.

This is highly coupled, and probably should be in model-view-controller format. So I'm finally going to change that.

Basically I want it to work like this.

> Controller has open a WebSocket Handler.
>
> WebSocket Handler returns to Controller a (1?).
>
> Controller uses (1?) calls Message Handler.
>
> Message Handler returns to Controller a (2?).
>
> Contoller uses (2?) to call Model.
>
> Model sends updates to appropriate places.

So there's two problems here.

1. First of all, when I'm getting a message in the WebSocket Handler, it is an instance of Tornado's WebSocketHandler, and I'm not sure how I can return anything to the Controller. Is the case simply that this is not possible? Do I have to keep a small amount of coupling between the WebSocket Handler and the Message Handler? I know I could always call a function in Controller, but that doesn't seem like an actual fix, just more function calls.
2. Is there a way to pass a function call around in python, keeping track of it's parameters while doing so? That would be the optimal way to go about doing this, but I don't think it's implemented in the python language. Otherwise, I feel like the best way to do it would be to return a dictionary with a field for the function name to be called, and fields for the parameters. This of course is a lot more code. If it can be avoided, I'd like to, but I'm not sure the direction in which to take this.

Thanks for the tips guys, this is a big refactoring and I'm really nervous about where to start.

Comment: Problem 2 could be solved with functools.partial. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, I believe you want to use partial functions.

Check out: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html

Basically you would go:

```
from functools import partial

function_call(partial(future_function_call, future_argument))
```